# Why is THEME_preprocess_node called twice?

Tags: 7, theming

I have an extremely simple test case a template.php file for the THEME theme, which contains the following:

```
THEME_preprocess_node( &$variable ) {
    msg( "Preprocess Node " . $variables[ 'vid' ] );
}
```

The `msg` function simples writes to a file (I was trying to abstract away all possible influence from other factors to sort out this issue).

If I clear the `msg` log and refresh a page, I always get two entries:

```
Preprocess Node 32
Preprocess Node 2 // <-- The front page
```

I have tried changing the front page through configuration and the log always reflects this. So if I change the front page to 3, I will get 3 in the log along with the actual node number.

It seems that `THEME_preprocess_node` is getting called twice, once for the actual node and once for the front page node.

Any reason why this would be happening?

Comment: If i am not wrong, `$variables[ 'vid' ]` is the vocabulary ids of nodes in homepage. THEME_preprocess_node get called for every node render.

Comment: on which page are you getting this? is it on the front page or some other page. do you have any other blocks in the page? as @David Thomas mentioned the theme function would be called every time a node is rendered. Even if it is in the block.

Comment: This is when I enter a node directly `node/32/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hook_preprocess_node is called for each and every rendered node

Comment: OK that makes sense, but say I open a standard node, example.com/node/32, should this be attempting to render node 32 as well as the front page node?

Comment: Maybe, it depends on your site configuration.

Comment: Ok fair enough, coming from different frameworks, it does seem tricky to debug or really narrow down where a problem is stemming from in Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

hook_preprocess_node will be called every time a render($content) method is invoked for a given node (say, in node.tpl.php). Based on the symptom above, my guess is there is a block or reference to the front page node, that is being output each page. I expect that it would be the "teaser" mode of the front page as well, but that's not clear from this debug. I ran into a similar issue today where preprocess_node was **not** being called at all, and it ended up being due to the fact that there was a custom page TPL in place that was not using any render() methods, but was instead using custom code to generate output.